# A dice is rolled 5 times,what is the joint probability?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables where X is the number of times that 1 has occurred and Y is the number of times that 6 has occurred.I want to calculate the joint probability of $X$ and $Y$.

I have began with trying to calculate the probability of having $1$ and $6$ appear once.
For this I have thought to take the probability of getting $1$ and $6$ once in $5$ rolls which will be $(\frac{1}{6})^{2}\cdot(\frac{4}{6})^3$ and then I need calculate the number of times $1$ and $6$ can be arranged in $5$ positions so that will be $p(5,2)=20$,
so $Pr[X=1,Y=1]=(\frac{1}{6})^{2}\cdot(\frac{4}{6})^3\cdot{p(5,2)}=\frac{80}{6^5}$.

And to jump to $Pr[X=1,Y=4]=(\frac{1}{6})^{5}\cdot{{5}\choose{4}}{{5}\choose{1}}=\frac{25}{6^5}$ here I thought I need to get four 6's and one 1's so for that I need $(\frac{1}{6})^{5}$ then I need the arrangements of these outcomes in 5 places which is ${{5}\choose{4}}$ to arrange the four 6's and i multiply that the number of arrangements of 1 five places which  5.

Is this the correct apporach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is correct.

The number of sequences with $x$ ones and $y$ sixes is $\binom{5}{x+y}\binom{x+y}{x}4^{5-x-y}$

First pick the $x+y$ positions that are one or six. Then pick which of those $x+y$ positions are ones, and finally do whatever you want with the other positions ( but they can't be one or six).

So the probability is

$$ \frac{\binom{5}{x+y}\binom{x+y}{x}4^{5-x-y}}{6^5}$$

Comment: Can you elaborate more please ? I don't understand why I would count $\binom{x+y}{x}$ to be the arrangements of 1 in the 5 places ? for example when I have two 6's and one 1's why wouldn't i do $\binom{5}{1}$ for 1?

Comment: because that symbol is the number of ways to select a number out of $5$, what does that have to do with what we want?

Comment: Lets say i have three 6's and two1's ,wouldn't i need to do $\binom{5}{3}\cdot{\binom{2}{2}}$ to get the number of arrangements? or for example $\binom{5}{2}\cdot{\binom{3}{1}}$ for arrangements of two 6's and one 1's?

Comment: $\binom 53\binom 22=\binom 5{2+3}\binom{2+3}2$  The LHS counts selections of $3$ from $5$ die and $2$ from the $2$ remaining.  The RHS counts ways to select $2+3$ from $5$ die and then $2$ from those $2+3$.

Comment: In short: $\binom 5{x+y}$ counts ways to select dice to show a required face (`1` or `6`) while $\binom{x+y}x$ counts ways to select which of *those* are to show `1`. Also:$$\small\begin{align}\binom 5{x+y}\binom{x+y}x&=\dfrac{5!}{(x+y)!(5-x-y)!}\dfrac{(x+y)!}{x!~y!}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{5!}{x!~y!~(5-x-y)!}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{5!}{y!(5-y)!}\dfrac{(5-y)!}{x!(5-x-y)!}\\[1ex]&=\binom 5y\binom {5-y}x\end{align}$$

Comment: Got it now thanks.